# More than 96 assemblies of .Net Standard 2 are copied to the bin folder of Console (.Net framework) Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

in vs 2017.3 preview 3, I created a solution with three projects: Netstandard2 library (.Net Standard v2.0 preview), Console applicationA (.Net framework) and Console applicationB (.Net core)

Both console applications reference the Netstandard2 library.

When I build the solution I find  all assemblies (96 dll file) of the Netstandard2 are  copied to the bin folder of the Console applicationA, while for Console applicationB (.Net core) are not copied.

Is this a normal to get all these 96 dll copied to the bin folder?

What I need to deploy the Console applicationA that depend on the Netstandard class libray to a new brand machine (windows 7 x86)? Do I need to install both .net 4.6.1 + dotnet-sdk2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have posted the question to [Github dotnet.standard project](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/415#issuecomment-314288712)

All credit go to  [@weshaggard](https://github.com/weshaggard) and  [@terrajobst](https://github.com/terrajobst)

Currently, the project authors don't do any smart trimming of the compat shims that come with the tooling so it ends up copying them all.

If the  dependencies don't rely on them, it is safe to delete/not-deploy them but doing it blindly may break some of the  dependencies.

There is [a tool](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/Microsoft.Packaging.Tools.Trimming/docs/trimming.md) they are working on to trim unnecessary binaries from the output:

Also, the project authors, deploy what's safe. .NET Standard 1.x requires all of these files. If only  binaries that target .NET Standard 2.0+ are consumed, There's  a way with fewer files.

However, there are still cases where some extra files beyond netstandard.dll (e.g.System.Net.Http, System.ValueTuple, System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, System.Data.Common).

Subsetting by hand is possible, but as Wes said:  application  should be  tested.

It's worth mentioning that with .NET Framework 4.7.1 and up you'll not have to deploy any extra files for .NET Standard. Today, that's already the case if you target Xamarin or .NET Core.

You can find the complete discussion in [Github dotnet.standard project](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/415#issuecomment-314288712)